# How can i make this time series graph interactive?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I am new to Python and Pandas so any help is much appreciated.

I am trying to make the graph below interactive, it would also be good to be able to choose which attributes show rather than them all.

Here is what I have so far

```
df.set_index('Current Year').plot(rot=45)
plt.xlabel("Year",size=16)
plt.ylabel("",size=16)
plt.title("Current year time series plot", size=18)
```

I know that i need to import the following `import plotly.graph_objects as go` but no idea how to implement this with the above time series graph. Thanks

EDIT

I am getting this error when trying to enter my plotted data.

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is:

```
df.plot()
```

As long as you import the correct libraries and set `plotly` as the plotting backend for `pandas` like this:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"

df = pd.DataFrame({'year':['2020','2021','2022'], 'value':[1,3,2]}).set_index('year')
fig = df.plot(title = "Current year time series plot")
fig.show()
```

#### Plot:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"

df = pd.DataFrame({'year':['2020','2021','2022'], 'value':[1,3,2]}).set_index('year')
fig = df.plot(title = "Current year time series plot")
fig.show()
```